# Prove that $\gcd(5x+2y,2x+y)=1$ if $\gcd(x,y)=1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

Let $\gcd(x,y)=1$. Prove that $5x+2y$ and $2y+x$ are always co-prime.

I’ve tried a lot of things (really a lot), but nothing has worked for me.

One of the best ideas that came to my mind (I think) is to use a proof by contradiction:

Suppose $\exists d >1$ Such that $d\mid 5x+2y$ and $d\mid 2x+y$.
After some modular arithmetic I’ve found that $d\mid x$ And $d\mid y$. But what does that mean?

Comment: What if $x=y=2$? The statement is false.

Comment: This is only true if gcd$(x,y)=1$

Comment: @DonThousand You are right.. I derived this in my answer.

Comment: What were the "a lot of things you tried?  Please show your work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **Tool:**  [Euclidean algorithm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm)

$$\begin{align}\gcd(5x+2y,2x+y)=
&\gcd(3x+y,2x+y)\\
=&\gcd(x,2x+y)\\
=&\gcd(x+y,x)\\
=&\gcd(x,y).\end{align}$$

So, we get

$$\gcd(5x+2y,2x+y)=\gcd(x,y)$$

This implies, if $\gcd(x,y)=1$, then $\gcd(5x+2y,2x+y)=1.$

Comment: See the edit @lone student

Comment: @Yassir Well, I think, my answer still seems to be valid ..

Comment: @Yassir I edited my answer after your edit.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use or show first that gcd $(a,b)$ = gcd$(a-b, b)$ then use this fact repeatedly will help you. You can show this fact using the definitions only.

Then gcd $ (5x+2y, 2x+y) $ = gcd $(3x+y, 2x+y)$ = gcd$(x, 2x+y)$ = gcd$(x, x+y)$. So the statement you are trying to prove is not true.

Example- Take $x = 3$ and $y = 12$.

Answer (score 0):

If $d$ divides  $5x+2y,2x+y$

$d$ must divide $5x+2y-2(2x+y)=x$

Similarly, $d$ must divide  $5(2x+y)-2(5x+2y)=y$

$\implies d$ must divide $(x,y)$

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$
\pmatrix{5x+2y \\ 2x+y}
=
\pmatrix{5 & 2 \\ 2 & 1}
\pmatrix{x \\ y}
$$
The matrix has determinant $1$ and so is invertible over $\mathbb Z$. Therefore, $x$ and $y$ can be expressed as integer linear combinations of $5x+2y$ and $2x+y$ and so have the same common divisors.